# save and load data from linked list to a binary file c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, binaryfiles

I made a classic linked list that simulates an array that can get any kind of type you want. Of course you can delete and add organs and all methods work fine.

Now I have to write methods for writing and reading from a binary file and I do not really know what to do
I've tried all sorts of ways to write to a file, and so far I have not been able to get anywhere and I do not even know what's wrong with the code,

thats part of my linked list code

```
    template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node * next;
    };
    node* head;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    void add(T value);
    int find(T value);
    bool remove(T value);
    void clear();
    bool ifEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    void display() const;
    T getData(int index) const;

    T &operator[](int index);


    void save(ofstream& out);
};
```

and thats the code of the save method that dosent work

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::save(ofstream& out)
{
    node* temp = head;
    T temp2 = temp->data;

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        out.write((const char*)(temp2), sizeof(temp2));
        temp = temp->next;
        temp2 = temp->data;
    }
}
```

please if some of you pros can give me a direction of how to do it right...

Comment: Look up "serialization". If `T` contains pointers reading the pointers back will not be useful.

Comment: yea i understand what your saying, but i can throw an exception not to use pointers or something right?

Comment: It's not so easy to figure out if `T` contains a pointer. What if it is a `private` member? Typically you would write something like a `std::string to_string(const T &t)` and `T from_string(const std::string &s)` function for various `T`s. For some types like `int` you can implement it yourself, for use-defined types the user needs to do it. Also look at libraries like [cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/).

Comment: @nwp Couldn’t you use [`std::is_trivially_move_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible) to tell if this type of serialization would work?

Comment: @DanielH [No](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/882858b7759e565a).

Comment: @nwp D’oh. I should have noticed that. Just because you don’t care if there are one or two instances doesn’t mean you don’t care if there are zero or one, especially if you restart the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the size of the list first. This will allow you to read the list. Without reading the size, there is no way for you to decide when to stop reading from the file.

Also, you have an error. The line

```
        out.write((const char*)(temp2), sizeof(temp2));
```

needs to be

```
        out.write((const char*)(&temp2), sizeof(temp2));
                                ^^ Missing
```

---

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::save(ofstream& out)
{
   size_t sz = size();
   out.write((const char*)(&sz), sizeof(sz));

   node* temp = head;
   T temp2 = temp->data;

   for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
   {
      out.write((const char*)(&temp2), sizeof(temp2));
      temp = temp->next;
      temp2 = temp->data;
   }
}
```

Potential read implementation.

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>:read(ifstream& in)
{
   size_t sz = 0;
   in.read((char*)(&sz), sizeof(sz));

   // Make sure that list is empty

   for ( size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i )
   {
      T temp;
      in.read((char*)(&temp), sizeof(temp));

      // Add temp to the list.
      add(temp);
   }
}
```

---

An updated version of `save` that should fix the null pointer access problem if `size()` returns the correct value.

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::save(ofstream& out)
{
   size_t sz = size();
   out.write((const char*)(&sz), sizeof(sz));

   node* temp = head;
   for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
   {
      // Pull the data out of the pointer here.
      // At this point, temp should not be NULL.
      T temp2 = temp->data;
      out.write((const char*)(&temp2), sizeof(temp2));
      temp = temp->next;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i tried your way but its keep crushing and i dont know why,  thats how i use it in main you think maybe i write it wrong? `ofstream outFile("test.txt",ios::binary);

  iList.save(outFile);

  outFile.close();`

Comment: @user8093201, try the debugger. Your use of `ofstream` and the `save()` function look fine to me. The problem is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: debugger said that temp was null ptr so i throw an exception and its not crushing now, but problem is that when i open the file that created its in gibrish even if i try to write a txt file just for checking, any way of knows for sure if its copy the right data?

Comment: @user8093201, 1. Make sure that `size()` returns the correct value. If it does, you can read the data back in. 2. You can write the data being written to the file to `stdout` and write the data being read from the file to `stdout` to make sure that they match.

Comment: thanks for the tip!, its works and it is the correct valeus Edit**: just see your edit and its works great, also cant find a way to check the read method, the read call is wrong for some reason

Comment: Why do you need the size? Can’t you just stop at EOF?

Comment: i tried to use the read method and add like that `(*this).add(temp);` , but its seems to do nothing, whats the best way of adding the value that i read into the list that call read method?

Comment: @DanielH, `size` is useful only if you save other data to the file. If nothing else is saved to the file, you can certainly count on EOF.

Comment: @user8093201, that should work. I can't tell you why it does not work without seeing the implementation of `add()`.

Comment: well thats add: `template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::add(T value)
{
 node *p, *q;
 if (head == NULL) {
  head = new node;
  head->data = value;
  head->next = NULL;
  return;
 }
 p = head;
 while (p->next != NULL)
  p = p->next;
 q = new node;
 q->data = value;
 q->next = NULL;
 p->next = q;
}`

Comment: @user8093201, Looking at that, it seems calling `add()` might be problematic. 1. You'll need to make sure that your list object is empty before you call `read()`. 2. The way you are adding the objects, the list will have the items in the reverse order than they were in the original list.

Comment: im not sure i understand you, add works great for me, its just not adding the value that i read from the file for some reason, and what do you mean by adding in the reverse order? its not ading at all, when i display the new list after read its still said its empty...

Comment: @user8093201, I take that back. `add` should work. Not sure why it doesn't.

Comment: i try to understand your edit to read method but cant figured it out, 1: i got a method `bool ifEmpty` that can help me cheak list is empty can use it like `*this.ifEmpty()` ?, 2: whats nptr for?, 3: still cant see when and how to use add method for getting the value into the list that call the `read`

Comment: @user8093201, sorry about that  previous `read` implementation. I updated it again.

Comment: now i can understand your code and it looks like its should work but for some reason cant read and the list that call `read` still stay empty, i call the file in main like this `ifstream inFile("test.dat", ios::binary | ios::in); test.read(inFile);` maybe thats wrong calling?